When running a Bayesian mixed effects regression, if a random effect estimate has 95% CIs that include zero, should it be disregarded?
Consider a Bayesian mixed effects regression.
I am interested in the correlation between two of the random slopes.
However, the 95% CIs for the correlation value include 0. Should I disregard the correlation because of that?

The credibility interval tells you about parameter values from the MCMC simulations. In some simulates, the parameter was estimated as 0. But if we are talking about a 95% CI that looks like [-0.05 0.75], then the bulk of the evidence (simulates) of the parameter estimate favor an interpretation of a positive correlation. What is the 95% CI in question? In general, Bayesian analysis should move one away from reject/not reject statistical thinking.

@ErikRuzek Bayesian analysis should move one away from reject/not reject statistical thinking similar comment/question I posted on Demetri's answer: why is the accept/reject mentality associated with the frequentist philosophy?

@dariober, perhaps I was not specific enough. I meant my comment to address the idea that an effect (or correlation in this case) is either there or not there. In Bayesian analysis you can utilize the posterior distribution to think more broadly about the parameter estimates. You can investigate the proportion of posterior draws that returned a correlation of 0 or lower. You can use alternate versions of CIs (some analysts do not look at 95% CIs, for example). There are times when you might still use a Bayesian analysis for a dichotomous decision, but the framework is more expansive.

@ErikRuzek thanks for getting back- I agree with what you and Demetri say. But I don't understand why one needs to go Bayesian to move away from the idea that an effect is either there or not there. If I say that a confidence interval is [-0.05 0.75] I'm not required to collapse to a yes/no answer because it crosses zero.

@dariober, I agree that you do not need to go Bayesian in order to take this perspective. In my opinion, Bayesian models provide a very handy set of estimates (in the form of the posterior) that you can interrogate for making more nuanced interpretations of the results. The problem is perhaps more with research practice than it is with frequentist vs. Bayesian. I do think the Bayesian interpretation of CIs, in particular, is much more intuitive than frequentist CIs.

I never understood why people would choose to use Bayesian methods, only to fall back onto frequentist tendencies.
In any case, my advice would be to make the decision by comparing models with and without the correlation structure. Even when CI contains 0, the estimated correlation can still be large enough to reduce uncertainty in the other parameters.  Ask yourself:

Does it make sense that the slope and intercept are correlated? Is there past work that verifies that correlation is present between these two parameters?
Is it important that the correlation be captured?
Are predictions, uncertainty, etc comparable between models?

There are far more important factors than just if some value is inside/outside the CI.  Think about the implications of including/excluding the correlation structure and base your decisions on implications from including/excluding that detail.

only to fall back onto frequentist tendencies It may be my ignorance but I don't see why the accept/reject tendency should be associated to frequentist thinking. Everything you say here applies also if you fit a frequentist mixed effect model. Similarly, in a Bayesian framework you still need to decide whether to include or not the correlation structure (for example).
